# GDAL failing to recognize OSM pbf file

Tags: gdal, openstreetmap, c#, .net

I'm using the GDAL .Net library to open a PBF file I've downloaded from the GeoFabrik website. The file opens fine in QGIS.

However when I call the Gdal.Open method on the file, it throws an exception stating:

> System.ApplicationException: '`south-africa-and-lesotho-latest.osm.pbf' not recognized as a supported file format.'

My code:

```
GdalConfiguration.ConfigureGdal();

var data = Gdal.Open("C:/south-africa-and-lesotho-latest.osm.pbf", OSGeo.GDAL.Access.GA_ReadOnly);
```

I find this weird since, when the ConfigureGdal method is called, it prints out a list of drivers to the output window, one of them being OSM PBF:

> GDAL 180: PGDUMP-PostgreSQL SQL dump
>
> **GDAL 181: OSM-OpenStreetMap XML and PBF**
>
> GDAL 182: GPSBabel-GPSBabel

I've made some changes to the GdalConfiguration class that gets created when installing the GDAL Nuget package. These changes include adjusting the directories to set the correct gdal data and driver directory, as well as setting the osminfo.ini config file.

The problem is, I don't actually know what those directories should contain to know for certain I've chosen the right ones.

Comment: Pretty sure there's an `OGR` namespace you should use instead; the ***O**pen**G**IS Simple Feature **R**eference* implementation holds the GDAL vector processing tools.

Comment: Ah... yep, I believe that was it, I switched to `OSGeo.OGR.Ogr.Open("C:/south-africa-and-lesotho-latest.osm.pbf", 0);` and it now loads fine. Thanks for the help, you can go ahead and add it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @geozelot If I try to use gdal2tiles with a PBF file, it tells me that it is not recognised. How can I solve this?

Comment: @Koba well, by not trying to create a raster tile coverage from vector dat ,) PBFs are usually compressed vector data files, and while, technically, nothing speaks against encoding raster data, it seems unlikey that GDAL could handle it. Check the OGR module instead, but also, if you need to convert vector data to raster tiles, you'd likely need a more extensive pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not familiar with the *C#/.NET* bindings for GDAL, the library usually divides raster and vector functionality in different namespaces:

- `GDAL` (***G***eospatial **D**ata **A**bstraction **L**ibrary) for
  raster data
- `OGR` (***O***pen**G**IS Simple Feature **R**eference) for vector data

I assume you need to use the appropriate `Open` function within the `OGR` namespace, as you confirmed in the comments.